# FileManager not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, nsfilemanager, xcode9

I have recently updated Xcode to latest version(Xcode9). After updating, in iOS 7 when I am trying to get the URL for app directory using FileManager, it gets crash
Here is my code, which was running before xcode update.

```
    var error:NSError?
    let manager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let docURL = try manager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:true);
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
    }
```

Comment: Note: don't declare an `error` variable like that, you don't need it. Also remove `let error1 as NSError`. Just have a `catch` and inside the block use the *automatically generated* `error` variable.

Comment: iOS7?  How do you write code in Swift under iOS 7?

Comment: 2% of devices are using iOS version under 9. If your project doesn't requires to be run specifically on iOS 7 you should get ride of it.

Answer (score 0):

That API no longer `throws` instead gives an array like `[URL]`, and then we can use the `first` element from that array for our use.

Usage:

```
if let docURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    // Use docURL
}
```

Comment: Does it crash or gets "caught"?